# Is it possible to extend a javascript object then 'erase' the extensions after use?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I want to add behavior to JS string such as

```
String.prototype.camelize = function () {
    return this.replace (/(?:^|[-])(\w)/g, function (, c) {
        return c ? c.toUpperCase () : '';
    });
};
```

However it is commonly agreed that modifying primitive type is a terrible idea.

Is there any patterns I can follow to temporarily assign functions to a type and remove after use? Or any thing similar to ruby's 'class << obj' that modify the prototype of one object only?

EDIT:
The point of doing this is to be able to use syntax like

name = s.camelize();

or

if (s.hyphenize().length < 8);

So please don't bother with static function approach.

Also, this question is actually more focused on how should one manipulate js objects to do more with less side effect.

Comment: what's wrong with just a regular function without modifying anything?

Comment: Why do you have to do this if it is only temporary? Or, why not `function camelize() { ... }`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do exactly what you are describing- a JavaScript object is just a bundle of properties, some of which are functions. So if you can create:

```
String.prototype.camelize = function () {
   return this.replace (/(?:^|[-])(\w)/g, function (, c) {
      return c ? c.toUpperCase () : '';
   });
};
```

Then you can equally call:

```
String.prototype.camelize = null;
```

Once you've done that,  your ability to `camelize` strings is eradicated.

Now, I'm sure you have good reasons for *wanting* to do things this way, but I can't imagine a situation where the thing you are proposing is the right thing to do. To do something like this in a more idiomatic way you could create a type that wraps a string and offers a `camelize` function or you could just bind that function to instances of your class - you could even drop it from a utility function library into your class. Throwing functions around is one of JavaScript's great powers.

Be aware that your aversion to utility functions is going to force you to take a lot of long-cuts if you are writing JavaScript. You might need to put some of your preconceptions on one side until you have got to grips with the foundations of the language ( what some might term *The Good Parts* ) and then revisit them when you have a stronger handle on it. It's not that you can't write correct code in JavaScript, but it is not like other languages that you have used and you have to fit your practices and philosophy to the language, rather than trying to force the language into the shape of your preconceptions. Everyone does that at first and JavaScript is so flexible that it *very nearly* works, but learning to use it in a more idiomatic way reaps big rewards as you go on.

Comment: `String.prototype.camelize = null` leaves alien presence, `delete` might be better.

Comment: Does `String.prototype.camelize=null` actually remove your camelize from the 'namespace', or will it create problems for someone else who wants their own version? On your language comments: my conclusion from the 5 or so languages I've used extensively is that a requirement for 'idiomatic programming' is almost always a response to a major flaw in the language (Verilog, in particular, is so badly designed that you *must* use patterns). JS seems, on my limited exposure, to be much the same.

Comment: @EML It does- you are removing it from the prototype, so it no longer exists for anything on that prototype chain. As @Leonid observes, setting it to `null` means it now has a value of `null` rather than it doesn't exist, which isn't the same because JavaScript. The mistake you are making about idiomatic language use is that the idiom is typically what gives a language it's expressiveness and power. Avoiding them makes all languages equally bad because it doesn't allow any of them to play to their strengths.